# How to remove these mystery spaces?

Tags: html, css

Sorry in advance for stupid question - i have one container and 5 inner divs. When inner divs has only text content it looks like this:
[image: without content]
But if i remove text content from all divs and add div with spans to first it will look like this 
[image: with div and spans in it]
If all divs except first (which has mixed content) has text content - like this:
[image]
CSS of container:

```
.list {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

CSS of inner divs:

```
.list > div {
    background-image: url();
    background-size: cover;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 752px;
    max-width: 1280px;
    padding: 0.7% 1.3% 0.3%;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rq9xLywg/) you can have a look at the entire HTML and CSS.

What's going on, is it some textNodes messing it up?

Comment: btw in your fiddle you first css selector has alot of elements in it you can use the universal selector `*` for all elements, just incase you didn't know :)

Comment: Yeah, i know, but folks advised me to use this selector, dunno why)

Comment: +1 for the diagrams making it very clear what is going on. However, it would be best to use a Code Snippet instead of a link to JSFiddle.

Comment: @AndyM A code snippet would indeed be great, but it doesn't exclude a JSFiddle link, where editing right off the bat is much easier to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just how `display: inline-block;` behaves when you put some content in. If you add `vertical-align: top;` to you `.list > div` CSS selector, then they will re-align to the top of their container regardless of content.

Comment: if i had to use inline-block, i generally added a float: left... should be the same right? (well in this case using inline-block would be meaningful... i know...)

Comment: @lucifer63 No need to feel stupid! `inline-block` has a lot of seemingly weird things in its spec that people don't anticipate or know about.